# Communication between gold dupe hammer closers and reopeners

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons

**What happened**

I closed a question as a dupe and it was later reopened by a user. Now, I have no idea why it was reopened, it is definitely a dupe of probably many posts. The link I gave solved the problem and gave a link to the docs.

**The edit**

Now, the OP did edit but just took out the unnecessary logs and put them into a, almost unreadable, single line stacktrace. But the problem is still the same.

**Don't lose faith**

This brings up several questions but first I would like to say that the gold dupe hammer has been a good tool and I think it should be extended to other close reasons. But *maybe* posts like this are a small part of why it hasn't been (we need to work out the kinks).

**How I tried to solve before bringing it to meta**

I tried to @username the reopener but I don't think this works. I also tried to look for the user in chats to see why this post should be reopened. But no luck.

First and foremost, I would like to know if I closed incorrectly so I can be more effective on the site. I don't think so but I would appreciate feedback.

**The question**

Next, I'm wondering if there should be a path of dialog between closers/reopeners so we can talk through these things without needing to bring it up on meta or flagging for a, already busy enough, Mod.

I was going to make this a feature request but I wanted some dialog first in case there is something in place already that I don't know about.

Comment: So there is a close/reopen battle between two gold badge holders? To be honest this isn't worth the time & effort of developing new features. From memory there is already a mitigation process for these conflicts, IIRC an automatic flag is raised in a mod queue for them to check it over.

Comment: @slugster I seem to recall that that is indeed the case.

Comment: Neither of you can close or reopen the question again. What would you do when you finish talking?

Comment: +1 Talking is good. It would be very nice to be able to use "@username" to communicate with closers and reopeners. Surely that communication would also help moderators decide what to do?

Comment: this liscussion severely lacks a picture of two users hitting each other with a big hammer

Comment: @slugster I wasn't looking for anything phenomenal. I mean like simply being able to ping the user as with editors or a reopen reason from the users. I think it could be helpful in many ways. But I didn't know they were put into a queue for mods...that's good to know. However, if we implement something between users then that could possibly ease the burden on the mods by not needing the queue.

Comment: @user2357112 heh, I actually wasn't thinking about that, good point. However, I still think it could be useful for users to know why things are happening.

Comment: @gnat sorry, [this is the best I can do](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/14/148811/2839988-2456700_superman_vs_thor.jpg) :P

Comment: @gnat: http://image.fg-a.com/Hammer1c.gif

Comment: you can close it again ofcourse and leave a comment why you closed it?

Comment: @AwalGarg No. You can only close/reopen as a dupe one time. Besides, I was trying for something that wouldn't cause a close/reopen war even if it were possible.

Answer (score 38):

The core problem might be that the re-open option doesn't have any dialog where you can put in an explanation why you believe the post should be re-opened. When I cast re-open votes, I try to leave a comment stating my reasoning behind it, but since it isn't mandatory, I tend to forget. Particularly when doing re-open reviews, where the re-opening was initiated by someone else.

And of course some re-openers just don't care about telling their reasoning.

I'd like to see something like:

> I believe this post should be re-opened. It is not a
>   [duplicate][unclear][off-topic][primarily opinion-based] for the
>   following reasons: [edit box here].

And then it should be possible for high-enough rep users to see the opening/close history, who cast the votes and their rationale behind it.

Comment: This is a good point. I actually was thinking about a re-open message after I posted this and laid down for bed. I don't think this would be a drastic change and it could definitely clear up misunderstandings/reasons.

Comment: I left a comment like that yesterday before reopening a question (actually, I didn't realize that my gold close power also gave me super reopen power, I thought I was just casting a vote).

Comment: +1. Make it a feature request?

Comment: @Bergi done. Just wanted to make sure there was support for such a thing first but mostly to make sure I hadn't missed a feature

Comment: when reopening a dupe, [edit with an informative summary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773 "see sections 2 and 3 here") is an option worth considering. Particularly because it looks so impressive in reopen queue when done right